# How can I get JSON object at specified path - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, metabase

I'm trying to get the element item_sku inside the JSON object at specified path.

I have this column and I want to extract only the item_sku to add in a column using postgresql.
What may I do to solve it?

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
select o.reference,
       o.id as "ord_id",
       o.created_at,
       o.aasm_state,
       o.payment_details -> 'payment_method' as "payment_method", 
       max(gr.updated_at) as "last_updated_at", 
       o.shipping_address -> 'country' as "country",
       (gr.request_body -> 0 #>> '{lines}') as ESD
```

Here the result I got:

```json
[{"item_sku": "60997070103", "image_url": "https://hahaha", "identifier": "7713128"}, {"item_sku": "60997070103", "image_url": "https://hahha", "identifier": "7713131"}, {"item_sku": "62007100402", "image_url": "https://hahha", "identifier": "7713129"}]
```

Here is the data from I'm trying to get the info:

```json
[{"lines": [{"item_sku": "60997070103", "image_url": "https://hahaha", "identifier": "7713128"}, {"item_sku": "60997070103", "image_url": "https://hahha", "identifier": "7713131"}, {"item_sku": "62007100402", "image_url": "https://hahha", "identifier": "7713129"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT gr.request_body #>> '{0,lines,0,item_sku}'` will result in "60997070103"

`SELECT gr.request_body #>> '{0,lines,1,item_sku}'` will result in "60997070103"

`SELECT gr.request_body #>> '{0,lines,2,item_sku}'` will result in "62007100402"

```
SELECT elt->>'item_sku' AS item_sku
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(gr.request_body#>'{0,lines}') AS elt
```

will result in

| item_sku |
| --- |
| 60997070103 |
| 60997070103 |
| 62007100402 |

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NYwDiOcq)

Comment: It solved. Thanks you very much!

And if I want to extract all the fields on the JSON object at specified path is there any formula to decompose all into columns at the same time?

Comment: then look at the [jsonpath type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH), [language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) and [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE)